# SQLite is not supported for Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight

Tags: sqlite, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

i having this issue now cause i try to use SQLite over windows phone 8.1 silverlight i used a lot of techniques to have a workaround but the issue not solved yet so i searched alot for this problem and i find that :

1. MS released SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1 SDK for non silverlight project but that doesn't work in my case which is silverlight project.
2. i make a new project which is Windows Phone 8.1 i find the released Extension for SQLite but my old project uses Assemblies Extension such as microsoft.phone.control and system.windows.interactivity which is not included in Windows Phone 8.1
3. finally i used my old windows phone 8.1 silverlight project however i added a class library
   project of type windows phone 8.1 class library which is support SQLite and get a reference of that project in my old WP8.1 silverlight but unfortunately it doesn't work too.

any suggestions or workarounds ??

Comment: Silverlight applications do not access data directly. They must do it through a web service on your web server. As long as your web server can talk to the database, so can you.

Comment: using web service will be a headache to my App cause lot of data will be manipulated so every time access DB through web service will cause performance issue.

Comment: i will try to re-code my app again on windows phone 8.1 that is the    only option which i had but i notice the Extensions in Assemblies Tab that i used in silverlight App not provided in windows phone 8.1 , Why ?? @Steve

Answer (score 0):

To clarify a few things...

- On #1 - MS does not release SQLite, it is an open source project
  (www.sqlite.org).
- On #2 - The WinRT app model has built-in
  replacements for most of the Microsoft.Phone.Controls.* areas and the
  System.Interactivity is replaced by the Behaviors SDK that should be
  pre-installed in Visual Studio
- On #3 - this will not work as you are
  trying to mix a Silverlight .NET profile with WinRT which is not
  compatable unless you are using Portable Class Library.  However I
  wouldn't try this with the PCL approach either as SQLite is a
  *native* component and you are trying to use it in Silverlight which isn't supported in that manner.  Using a managed fork of SQLite
  (CsharpSqlite) might work here, but that is also an open source
  project and I think a bit stale at this point.

Comment: you can find in that [link](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d97faf6-39e3-4048-a0bc-adde2af75d1b) MS official extension for only windows phone 8.1 not a silverlight

Comment: i tried Community.CsharpSqlite.SQLiteClient and it deosn't work too

Comment: i tried to Manually hacking the SDK from this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815098/sqlite-wp81-extension-sdk-installs-on-vs2013-u2-but-unable-to-reference-assembly) but the Results was not different much